stereo_image_proc produces disparity map but all points are zero
I am running into a problem where using the stereo_image_proc library on ROS2 Humble I am able to produce a disparity image but when I run the disparity through the pointcloud node all the points are being set to zero.
The Disparity image is being published at 15hz as is the point_cloud
In rviz I am able to "visualize" the point cloud however all the points appear to be at the origin. The frame in rviz is set to the frame of the point cloud so I don't believe thats the issue.
I've checked that all my topics are being subscribed to correctly and that the camera_info topic is filled in.

ROS: Humble
Camera: DepthAI OAK-DW PRO
Package: stereo_image_proc

Here is my camera info, the camera comes pre-callibrated
I saw this issue previously posted https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/496 But it would seem that the parameter they were discussing is not zero on my end.
Attached the camera_info, screenshots, and the bag file below
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1718816076
    nanosec: 963032400
  frame_id: oak_left_camera_optical_frame
height: 400
width: 640
distortion_model: rational_polynomial
d:
- 5.650508880615234
- 1.3171125650405884
- 0.0004939142381772399
- -0.00010328910138923675
- -0.012967421673238277
- 6.00731897354126
- 3.039529323577881
- 0.07935015112161636
k:
- 285.8879699707031
- 0.0
- 326.58428955078125
- 0.0
- 285.8879699707031
- 200.15931701660156
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
r:
- 0.9999890327453613
- -0.004684998653829098
- 3.593681685742922e-05
- 0.004685017745941877
- 0.999988853931427
- -0.0005544650484807789
- -3.333874701638706e-05
- 0.0005546273314394057
- 0.9999998211860657
p:
- 285.88848876953125
- 0.0
- 324.9316101074219
- 21.49364359782485
- 0.0
- 285.88848876953125
- 203.0627899169922
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
- 0.0
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi:
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: false



Bag File
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
